# Use of unresolved identifier 'SWTableViewCel'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a very strange problem here to do with SWTableViewCell.
I know I've implemented it right as I can subclass my prototype cell in the IB.

I get an unresolved identifier error when trying to create a SWTableViewCell programatically or subclass it to use as a custom cell.

Does anyone know why I would be able to subclass it in the IB but not reference it programatically without getting an unresolved identifier error?

Comment: I guess you are using this class in a custom class of yours. What you can do is inherit this class into your class and then you can use it to instantiate objects.

Comment: Looking at the error in your title, might it be as simple as a spelling error in your storyboard?  i.e. "`Cel`" instead of "`Cell`"?

Comment: You need to post the actual and complete error message.